# How to filter a catalog by date when importing intake in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, intake

I have the following code

```
import intake
import pandas as pd

# Importing json file
catalog_file = "../my/path/path.json"

#using `intake` to manage the data
cat = intake.open_esm_datastore(catalog_file)

# Furthering filtering the data 
hits = cat.search(variable_id="var", frequency="30minutes")

#Loading the data
dataset_dict = hits.to_dataset_dict(cdf_kwargs={"chunks": {"time": 1}})
```

now, I've got an error when using `.to_dataset_dict`. The error basically says that it cannot find the first *.nc file:

```
OSError: 
            Failed to open netCDF/HDF dataset.

            *** Arguments passed to xarray.open_dataset() ***:

            - filename_or_obj: /work/bm1235/k203123/experiments/ngc2009/run_20200204T000000-20200218T235920/ngc2009_atm_2d_30min_inst_20200208T000000Z.nc
            - kwargs: {'chunks': {'time': 1}}

            *** fsspec options used ***:

            - root: /work/bm1235/k203123/experiments/ngc2009/run_20200204T000000-20200218T235920/ngc2009_atm_2d_30min_inst_20200208T000000Z.nc
            - protocol: None

            ********************************************
```

The data is complete from the 9.02.2020 (September 9th, 2020) onwards. The error comes from a *.nc file with data for day  08.02.2020 (August 2nd, 2020).

I am not an expert in `intake` an I was just wondering if there is a way to filter/select the data from 9.02.2020 until 1.03.2022.

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_json()`?

Comment: This appears to be specific to intake-esm rather than intake in general. Can you confirm, though, that the given file exists? Can you open that path directly with xarray?

Comment: @mdurant When I tried to open the file using axrray I got this:    `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/work/bm1235/k203123/experiments/ngc2009/run_20200204T000000-20200218T235920/ngc2009_atm_2d_30min_inst_20200208T000000Z.nc'`

Comment: @MarkMoretto No, I haven't try `pandas.read_json()`. Would that be better?

Comment: MarkMoretto - this is a netCDF file, not JSON. @jeiL, you'll need to follow up with the creator of the catalog to find out why there is no file at the location it should be.

Comment: I have asked them. They say some files are not longer available, but did not gave much details on it. So instead of having data from January 2020 until March 2022, the data starts in February 2020. Is there a way to filtered those missing files and then apply `.to_dataset_dict`? maybe in `search`?

Comment: @mdurant Thanks for the clarification. Pandas read_json() can be sketchy, so maybe it isn't the best tool for this.  Cheers!

Comment: I finally got an answer from the creator of the catalog. It turns out that catalog was an old one and they gave me the one that works! :)